# why the event is 'wait/io/table/sql/handler' when waiting for a row lock?

Tags: mysql

I made session B waiting  for row  lock hold by session A , however I saw the waiting is  'wait/io/table/sql/handler'  instead  of I expected  row lock  such  as 'wait/lock .....',the following  are  the  steps to duplicate the  issue .

MySQL version  is '5.7.18-debug';

step 1),enable  the  performance schema

```
UPDATE performance_schema.setup_instruments
       SET ENABLED = 'YES', TIMED = 'YES'
UPDATE performance_schema.setup_consumers
       SET ENABLED = 'YES'
```

step 2 ,create the table and insert a row .

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = InnoDB;
INSERT INTO t (i) VALUES(1);
```

step 3, start a new session A  hold a row lock ,and doesn't  release it .

```
 SELECT connection_id() ;
 START TRANSACTION;
 DELETE FROM t WHERE i = 1;
```

step 4, start a new session B  and try to get a  row lock, however  blocked by session A

```
 SELECT connection_id() ;
 START TRANSACTION;
 SELECT * FROM t  WHERE i = 1 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

step 5, then query the performance schema below , however from the PS tables  I saw the 'wait/io/table/sql/handler' for session B from table events_waits_current , which is meaning waiting for the  IO operation , doesn't it should be wait for a row  lock ?

```
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.events_waits_current;
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.events_stages_current;
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.events_statements_current;
```

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, this doesn't make any sense.
I've reproduced this as well as other issues with wait/io/table/sql/handler.
TL;DR is that wait events are of questionable use on MySQL.

The wait wait/io/table/sql/handler shows up for

I/O - reading data from disk

CPU - reading data blocks in the cache

LOCKs - two users trying to update the same row for example.

What's the point of a wait event if it covers things as broad as I/O, CPU and Locks?

Amazon Aurora has at least patched up the locking part by creating a new wait event synch/mutex/innodb/aurora_lock_thread_slot_futex
see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/ams-waits.waitsynch.html

I spent some time late last year going through some of the MySQL code and was surprised to see this wait "wait/io/table/sql/handler" wrapped around buffer reads from the cache which is simply a CPU state.
It is a bit ironic that Oracle manages MySQL and Oracle is that database the blazed the trail on wait events which work superbly in Oracle yet are so broken on MySQL.

Comment: Do you happen to have any references to documentation or information on how you came to this conclusion?

Comment: https://www.kylehailey.com/post/mysql-waits-and-cpu

https://www.kylehailey.com/post/are-some-mysql-wait-events-actually-cpu-time


https://www.bobbydurrettdba.com/2019/02/12/one-query-in-mysql-performance-schema/